# Masstransit sending ICommand

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a list of ICommand that I store in the DB for a legacy process manager (I don't have time to convert all the code to using Sagas just yet)

I need to be able to deserialize the list of commands and send them.

In order to be able to represent the commands in c# I have a List

looping through the list and calling send on each one causes a problem because Masstransit only sees an ICommand and not the underlying type (even though the commands are serialized with type info

Here is an example of the code:

```
if (deserializedCommands == null)
{
   deserializedCommands = this._serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Envelope<ICommand>>>(undispatched.Commands).ToList();

   while (deserializedCommands.Count > 0)
   {
       var cmd = deserializedCommands.First();

       this._commandBus.Publish(cmd.Body).Wait();

       deserializedCommands.RemoveAt(0);
   }
}
```

Hovering over cmd.Body in the debugger shows the correct type.

But Masstransit only sees ICommand:

> A convention for the message type xxxx.ICommand was not found

How can I make it so MT sees the correct type?

Googling brings up something about EndpointConvention but it doesn't look like it's documented or complete, there's also talk about topology but i can't find anything about that.

What can I do to make this work? I am using the castle windsor integration and loading my command handlers through `ep.LoadFrom(container);`

[UPDATE]

I can get the underlying type of the message using:

```
var type = cmd.Body.GetType();
```

Is there anyway to use that type as a generic argument for:

```
this._commandBus.Send(cmd.Body).Wait();
```

I guess is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the concrete object from your database, and are deserializing it properly, use the `object` overload of `Send` in MassTransit, rather than using the interface overloads. By making it an object, MassTransit will determine the type at runtime and use the matching serializer for the actual object type instead of the interface type specified.

Comment: Works like a charm and after me faffing about with all sorts of (much much much more complicated) stuff to make it work - such a simple solution that worked immediately was immense :) thank you! :)

Comment: You aren't the first who has experienced this issue. As I'm sure you've guessed by now.

Comment: There's a smooth solution and TBF the docs warn against my scenario! I'm updating some old code and want to transition iteratively and this hit the sweet spot

Answer (score 1):

If you know the underying message type, you can use `context.TryGetPayload<T>` to retrieve the object you need.

Comment: Is this on the receiving end?

Comment: the problem with this is that the message only contains the properties specified in ICommand which is just an ID

Comment: Inside the consumer you should call the method I wrote in my answer. But I misunderstood you. You want to send, and there Chris already answered.